# Checking if page has 'sameorigin'

Tags: javascript

I got a script that takes urls from a txt file and puts them into a frame, calculating the time it took for each frame to load. Everything works fine until i enter a url witch has iframe protection ('sameorigin'), then my script crashes and doesnt give results of other urls.

Here is my current script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get("imones.txt", function (data) {
        var array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
        var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();
        var loadTimes = [];
        var beforeTimes = [];
        $('#frame_id').on('load', function () {
            beforeTimes.push(beforeLoad);
            loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime());
            $('#frame_id').attr('src', array.pop());
            $.each(loadTimes, function (index, value) {
                var result = (value - beforeTimes[index]) / 1000;
                if (result < 0) {
                    result = result * (-1);
                }
                $("#loadingtime" + index).html(result);
                beforeLoad = value;
            });
        }).attr('src', array.pop());
    });
</script>
```

**I do not want to bypass the 'sameorigin' protection, *i just want to skip any url that is protected*.**

Searching to solve this issue i found this on stackoverflow - http://jsfiddle.net/LHjwZ/11/

I do not understand that code at all, but if i enter an url that is protected (google.com for example), it returns a `truefalse` , if i enter url without protection it returns a `falsefalse`. So i assume it somehow detects if url has 'sameorigin' and returns `true` if it has it. I would like to put that jsfiddle piece of code into my code, but like i said i dont understand how that code works.

Comment: Have you tried using an exception handler so that your script can "handle" a same origin exception and continue on with the other URLs?

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? What errors do you get? Can you setup a self-contained example on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: by crash i mean it wont load any other url values, it displays nothing

Answer (score 0):

The code uses a **try...catch** statement:

```
try {
    // Put your regular code here
}
catch(e){
    // put here the code to execute in case of error
    // you can leave the catch section empty
}
```

For more info, check out the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).